# Debug JS Remotely not showing up in developer tools option for emulator in Android Stuido

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-debugger

I'm trying to set up react-native-debugger standalone tool. Both metro and the debugger are connected to port 8081 on localhost but they dont seem to be connected to each other. The debugger is stuck on "waiting for client to connect". On top of this, when I open up the dev tools using ctrl+m there is no remote debugging option, only debug, which crashes the application with no error messages to the console. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have figured this out yet?  I am experiencing the same and can't see the option to Remote Debug

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964991/7390929

Comment: @LucasAndrade can you see the dates on the questions and realise that if its a duplicate, the other one is the duplicate and not this one. thank you

Comment: You're right, sorry I didn't check that. But the answer for your question is on the link.