# Missing Debug JS Remotely option in Developer Menu

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

In order to use React Native Debugger, I don't see the option 'Debug JS Remotely' when I open the Developer Menu both on my android simulator and my physical device, using expo. Tried both scenarios and no option for Debug JS Remotely...

(I originally wanted to use my external device with React Native Debugger and I can't find the setupDevtools.js file at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js in order to update this file for use.  I don't know if these two might be related, but also wanted to share)

Am I missing something?  Thank you...

Comment: I have the same issue! I only have the option `Debug`

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, anybody find anything out?

Comment: I've tried with the latest version of expo, it mentions the 'Debug JS remotely', but only allows you to debug locally. This functionality works fine without expo. You'll find many cases where expo doesn't quite manage, and you would either have to eject, or just start a project without it (I recommend this, to avoid all the bloat expo packages that you don't need).

Answer (score 6):

I guess the option `Debug JS Remotely` has been replaced by the option `Debug` with the latest version of react-native.

And If you want to use your external device with a debugger just shake the device and select the debug option from the developer menu.

But as @JoeBe suggested you should also look for an already open debugger and then try it.

You can also open the developer menu just by pressing `d` on node.js screen if you are using the latest version of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But as it turns out, after terminating all other debuggers it was working with that `Debug` option as well.

Answer (score 0):

this package enables "debug js remotely"

https://github.com/gusgard/react-native-devsettings

worked for me with rn 0.73.1 (not with expo tho)